# Word for the process of analysing characteristics of the ideal solution to a particular problem

Tags: single-word-requests

Simple example problem: you spilt some milk onto the floor

Characteristics of the ideal solution: the floor should be clean/dry

Is there a word that describes the action of intentionally undertaking the above analysis to find the characteristics of the correct solution?

Comment: As the tag states, single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: I tried to write a sentence to describe how the word would be used. I struggle to write a sample sentence, for the same reason that it would be difficult to write a sample sentence in which Philosophy would be used (without referring to its definition). If not for single word requests, to where might I be able to submit this question to get an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't cleaning/drying the floor the solution itself ? What exactly do you mean by "characteristics of the ideal solution"?

Comment: Please note the difference between the description of the floor as needing to be clean/dry at the end (a characteristic/condition/detail of the solution) and cleaning/drying the floor(applying the solution). Without deciding that the floor should be clean/dry, you could come to the conclusion that leaving the spill as-is is an acceptable solution.

Comment: But isn't a dry floor the *desired* ***result***? The solution required to *achieve* that result would be something like *use a paper towel*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Were this a mathematical example we would say that we are “developing” a solution. The development of a solution takes into account the nature of the problem, the constraints on solving it, and the choice of method of solving. The choice of method may lead to “optimising” the solution.

This sounds a bit formal when considering split milk!

Comment: Someone disbelieves me. Would they like to say why?

Comment: This was the closest thing I got to an answer, so thanks. Unfortunately my votes don't count. Overall I guess a single word probably doesn't exist. Frankly, I regret asking this question because people started nitpicking the example I gave instead of trying to answer the question (... crying about spilt milk :D), so thank you for having some semblance of reading comprehension.

Comment: Kind of you, and thanks. I don’t really care about points; what matters is that we help each other and enjoy the pleasures of English. I suppose that, for some folk - even for me at times - this means nitpicking. C’est la vie.

Answer (score -1):

In OP's context, the fact of the floor being "clean / dry" is a ***prerequisite*** of any solution (realistically, it's probably a necessary characteristic of ***any*** solution, not just "ideal" ones).

> **prerequisite** [(lexico.com)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/prerequisite)
> *A thing that is required as a prior condition for something else to happen or exist*